pyspark 403 error trying to access openly available AWS S3 bucket
I am running a local dockerised Spark 3.5.3 with Hadoop 3.3.4. I want to download binary files from an openly available AWS S3 bucket, so I am trying the following python script:
import findspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

findspark.init()
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ReadBinaryFilesFromPublicS3") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "none") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "none") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.signature", "none") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com") \
    .getOrCreate()

binary_files_df = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load(f"s3a://my-bucket-name/path/to/files/*")


Side note: I am trying to set signature to none, because previously I managed to download files one-by-one sucessfully with boto3 library using the following code:
s3_client = boto3.client("s3", config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
s3_client.download_file("my-bucket-name", "path/to/files/filename, my_local_filename)

But Spark returns the following error:
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://my-bucket-name/path/to/files/*: getFileStatus on s3a://my-bucket-name/path/to/files/*: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: DPKPZWH7HY8YDX61; S3 Extended Request ID: YoV3ws/nFtE06tg/9oU2SGHp5gabb2WDbOD/+UkK4h95QCjHGNhn1mnCNOl38btZePNFlsl00AInFBbVdC/Fkde+3W4Ne+DIJGawfY9DPS4=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: YoV3ws/nFtE06tg/9oU2SGHp5gabb2WDbOD/+UkK4h95QCjHGNhn1mnCNOl38btZePNFlsl00AInFBbVdC/Fkde+3W4Ne+DIJGawfY9DPS4=:InvalidAccessKeyId

Apart from the fact that I could not simply find any information in any docs on how to connect to open buckets: why am I getting these errors if I can even access the files directly from my browser with HTTPS URL? If I remove access and secret key configuration lines:
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "none") \
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "none") \

or change values "none" to "", I am getting errors that they are missing, as follows:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.load.
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://my-bucket-name/path/to/files/*: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))

Thanks in advance for any hints on how to solve this.

Apparently access via https://, and access via s3a://, are getting treated differently. "If I remove access and secret key configurations, I am getting errors that they are missing." - if access via s3a:// requires them, then you will have to provide them ... and correct ones, which apparently you currently are not doing.

@C3roe what I mean is when I remove these two lines     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "none") \     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "none") \ or change "none" to "". I also tried to export AWS_SECRET_KEY "" and export AWS_ACCESS_KEY "" in the terminal before running the script. No difference.

Would it mean that at the same time I can access the files via https:// and must provide some credentials for the same files via s3a://?

Well if you get an error if you don't provide credentials, I'd say the answer to that question is very obviously Yes ...?

Well, I used boto3 lib and provided no credentials nor signature to download these files without any problem. Hence the question, because it seems as if there was something different in Spark integration with AWS.

"If I remove access and secret key configurations, I am getting errors that they are missing." - from Amazon S3 itself - or from the framework you are using? Anonymous access appears possible (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Anonymous_Login_with_AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider), but it might require additional configuration, I suppose.

I added the error to the question description. The errors I am getting are through Spark and py4J in general, and I would rather avoid direct Spark/Hadoop configuration as long as it is possible.

Try AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider
spark = (
  SparkSession.builder
    .appName("ReadBinaryFilesFromPublicS3")
    .config(
      "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
      "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider"
    )
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
    .getOrCreate()
)

And yes, http and s3 access are different from auth point of view.

That was it, thanks so much! It's frustrating for Spark beginners how such things are tricky to find in the docs.
